# container not found on pod error in jenkins

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

We are running a `jenkins` pipeline with a declarative pipeline. One of the agent containers was using too much ephemeral storage, so we thought of adding a persistent volume to the container to tackle that.

We added a `workspaceVolume` but now it is getting a different error:

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException:
> io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: container
> flutter not found in pod  at
> io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.core.v1.PodOperationsImpl.validateOrDefaultContainerId(PodOperationsImpl.java:344)

I am also at loss to find logs about what is causing it. Tailing `pod` logs show that the jnlp container gets created on the `pod`, then suddenly it errors out, cannot see what is happening in between.

I can see that the dynamic `PVC` is getting created and is getting assigned to the `pod`, after that the jnlp can be seen and then the error.

Describing pvc shows:

```
Successfully provisioned volume ocid1.volume.oc1.region.abvgkljrua6fyyqikxedgj337hzv7xkjybnenthp72cpfoyvf5r742sd3w4q
```

Events show:

```
21m         Warning   FailedScheduling         pod/fluttered-mobile-android-46-7s3mb-sq4b5-1bbxj                                                            0/6 nodes are available: 6 persistentvolumeclaim "pvc-workspace-fluttered-mobile-android-46-7s3mb-sq4b5-1bbxj" not found. preemption: 0/6 nodes are available: 6 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
21m         Warning   FailedScheduling         pod/fluttered-mobile-android-46-7s3mb-sq4b5-1bbxj                                                            0/6 nodes are available: 6 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/6 nodes are available: 6 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
21m         Normal    Scheduled                pod/fluttered-mobile-android-46-7s3mb-sq4b5-1bbxj                                                            Successfully assigned default/fluttered-mobile-android-46-7s3mb-sq4b5-1bbxj to 10.0.10.223
21m         Normal    SuccessfulAttachVolume   pod/fluttered-mobile-android-46-7s3mb-sq4b5-1bbxj                                                            AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "ocid1.volume.oc1.region.abvgkljrfwf3fknno2yz4776oachzlewpbzajjz4whjaw5wlthheg3kifmiq"
20m         Normal    Pulled                   pod/fluttered-mobile-android-46-7s3mb-sq4b5-1bbxj                                                            Container image "jenkins/inbound-agent:3107.v665000b_51092-4" already present on machine
20m         Normal    Created                  pod/fluttered-mobile-android-46-7s3mb-sq4b5-1bbxj                                                            Created container jnlp
20m         Normal    Started                  pod/fluttered-mobile-android-46-7s3mb-sq4b5-1bbxj                                                            Started container jnlp
20m         Normal    Killing                  pod/fluttered-mobile-android-46-7s3mb-sq4b5-1bbxj                                                            Stopping container jnlp
20m         Warning   VolumeFailedDelete       persistentvolume/ocid1.volume.oc1.region.abvgkljrfwf3fknno2yz4776oachzlewpbzajjz4whjaw5wlthheg3kifmiq   failed to delete volume from OCI: Error returned by Blockstorage Service. Http Status Code: 409. Error Code: Conflict. Opc request id: 76ecc82dad7a3241de2a70fbc91895c8/0916D58101760EDEDB599936BABBF1D9/39E5A4B955F935D7253BB1AC197BEFDD. Message: Volume ocid1.volume.oc1.region.abvgkljrfwf3fknno2yz4776oachzlewpbzajjz4whjaw5wlthheg3kifmiq may not be deleted while attached to an Instance.....
```

It takes some time for PVC to attach, then it starts jnlp container and then stops jnlp container.
There is also an error that cannot delete the PVC volume.

I tried to get the shut down jnlp logs with -p but that was not possible (I have done this for crashloopbackoff containers)

below is agent configuration from pipeline:

```
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            workspaceVolume dynamicPVC(accessModes: 'ReadWriteOnce', requestsSize: "100Gi", storageClassName: "oci")
            yaml '''
          apiVersion: v1
          kind: Pod
          spec:
            securityContext:
              fsGroup: 1000
              runAsGroup: 1000
              runAsUser: 1000
          containers:
          - name: ubuntu
            image: ubuntu:latest
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
          - name: git
            image: git:latest
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
          - name: curl
            image:alpine-curl-jq:latest
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
          - name: flutter
            image: flutter_image:2.10.1
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
          - name: build
            image: flutter_image:2.10.1
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
          imagePullSecrets:
          - name: ocirsecret
        '''
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your YAML is not correctly formatted. The containers need to go under the spec

```
    agent {
    kubernetes {
        workspaceVolume dynamicPVC(accessModes: 'ReadWriteOnce', requestsSize: "100Gi", storageClassName: "oci")
        yaml '''
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Pod
      spec:
        securityContext:
          fsGroup: 1000
          runAsGroup: 1000
          runAsUser: 1000
        containers:
        - name: ubuntu
          image: ubuntu:latest
          command:
          - cat
          tty: true
        - name: git
          image: git:latest
          command:
          - cat
          tty: true
        - name: curl
          image:alpine-curl-jq:latest
          command:
          - cat
          tty: true
        - name: flutter
          image: flutter_image:2.10.1
          command:
          - cat
          tty: true
        - name: build
          image: flutter_image:2.10.1
          command:
          - cat
          tty: true
        imagePullSecrets:
        - name: ocirsecret
    '''
}
```

}